# Links in blog posts

Tags: php, hyperlink, blogs

Consider this link

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21657/what-did-the-original-stack-overflow-look-like
```

As you can see this is a link to a StackExchange page. This has a pattern in it like `www.websitename.com/title_of_the_page`. How does this link open up a answer page? Is there a folder called `title_of_the_page` or how to write a PHP script that can get this `title_of_the_page` from the link?

Comment: "url routing" is the term you need.

Comment: You could use one of the available routers, define your route patterns and get parts of the url. The title_of_the_page would then be captured in a variable.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No there is not any folder called the title of the page and should not be. It's all about rewrite rule. The number you are seeing in the link is the actual id of the question which is the main thing in the url. If you only use the id like

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21657
```

it gets redirected to the original url. Consider reading this article:
https://www.tinywebhut.com/redirect-all-urls-to-proper-version-of-urls-38

Moreover, this is the best practice for Search Engine Optimization(SEO).